# Accessing object data in datatables through get function

Tags: javascript, datatables

I am trying to create an object that I can modify as per

[Datatables - Data](https://datatables.net/manual/data/)

I use the following code to create my object

```
function projectData(projid,projdesc,descdet){
  this._projid = 'HTML1'
  this._projdesc = 'HTML2'
  for(var i=0;i<=7;i++){
    this['_day'+i] = 'HTML3';
  }
  this.projid = function(){
    return this._projid
  }
  this.projdesc = function(){
    return this._projdesc
  }
  this.day0 = function(){ // More of these for day (0-7)
    return this._day0
  }
}
```

Then I use the following table initialization. (prjData is an array of New projectData objects)

```
  var table = $('#table-ProjectHours').DataTable({
    data: prjData,
    "columns": [
        { data: 'projid',"visible": true},
        { data: 'projdesc',"width": "45%" },
        { data: 'day0',"orderDataType": "dom-text-numeric" },
        { data: 'day1',"orderDataType": "dom-text-numeric" },
        { data: 'day2',"orderDataType": "dom-text-numeric" },
        { data: 'day3',"orderDataType": "dom-text-numeric" },
        { data: 'day4',"orderDataType": "dom-text-numeric" },
        { data: 'day5',"orderDataType": "dom-text-numeric" },
        { data: 'day6',"orderDataType": "dom-text-numeric" },
        { data: 'day7',"orderDataType": "dom-text-numeric" }
    ]
  });
```

I access my table through

```
var dto = $('#table-ProjectHours').DataTable().data();
```

I get my objects as seen here:

[image: Datatable object]

What I do not understand is why when I attempt to do dto[0].day0 I do not get _day0 --- I just get the function string.

I can access the data through _day0 but it seems wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to set data in jquery-datatables you must use `.row(index).data(obj)` or `.cell(selector).data(obj)`.

You can also use `row(index).day0()` and if you write a set portion of your method you can set the data like `row(index).day0(thing_to_set)` You must call `row(index).invalidate` after changing the data for it to appear correctly.

In this particular situation, .`day0` must be called as `.day0()` since it is a method.

Answer (score 0):

Try rows().data() https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().data()

e.g.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

var data = table
    .rows()
    .data();

alert( 'The table has '+data.length+' records' );
```

Comment: `alert(dt[0].projid)` -> Returns "`function (){return this._projid}`"
`alert(dt[0]._projid)` -> Returns "`<span id="projid-5">5</span>`", regardless of `.rows().data()` or `.data()`

Comment: What are you trying to do?  To access the row, look at the rows api:  https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows()

Comment: `rows.data()` only gets the data. I have determined data tables only allows setting via `.row(index).data(obj)` and `.cell(selector).data(value)`  I am trying to access my `obj.projid` value so I can manipulate it and then return it to `.row(index).data(obj)`  But something is wrong with the obj.projid method I have defined in projectData

Comment: I am terrible. Since .projid is a method I have to call .projid()